# CLucene+Qt собрал библиотеку но не могу найти файла сборки

Tags: c++, qt, include, lucene

Произвел сборку библиотеки **CLucene ** (через msys в Windows), выполнил такие действия:

```
The following will get you building assuming that you have suffciently
recent buld tools installed.  
1.) unpack tarball 
2.) cd into clucene
3.) if you downloaded a tar version skip to 5
4.) run ./autogen.sh
5.) run ./configure
6.) run make
7.) things will churn for a very long time, the clucene library will
be built as well as the examples.
8.) check the src/demo, test and src directory
```

Но так и не понял, где найти файлы, которые нужно объявить в include в своем проекте, чтобы была возможность задействовать классы из библиотеки CLucene.

---

Подскажите куда посмотреть, чтобы разобраться в этом вопросе. Или может я делаю вовсе что-то не так. Если у кого-то есть уже собранная библиотека, если не сложно поделитесь пожалуйста. В любом случае буду благодарен любой мысли.

--
Я выполнил команду : **make install**

```
make[2]: *** [Makefile:597: StdHeader.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/e/test2/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1555: install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/e/test2/src'
make: *** [Makefile:313: install-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: Шаг 8 надо было выполнить. Там в примере показано, как использовать.

Comment: Через что возможно открыть этот пример как проект? Через Qt он не открывается

Comment: Я пробовал src/demo, но файлы по этому пути не открыть как проект или библиотеку, подскажите как быть?

Comment: В блокноте открывайте, как текстовые файлы.

Comment: Зачем мне смотреть на эти файлы?! Мне нужно их включить в свой проект для того, чтобы использовать возможности написанных классов. Поэтому ваш комментарий не по делу. Все же вопрос звучал как сделать так, чтобы можно было использовать классы Clucene, а не только посмотреть.

Comment: Как вы считаете какие есть способы конкретного использования CLucene?

Comment: Странно, что здесь нет make install. Эта команда раскладывает все файлы (в том числе подключаемые) по своим местам. В случае с msys это внутри каталога его установки в одной из папок (смотря какую конфигурацию вы используете). Но вы можете указать и своё расположение с помощью параметра --prefix скрипта configure. Найдите там файлы и укажите путь к ним в настройках вашего проекта.

Comment: Можете поподробнее рассказать как использовать команду "--preffix"?

Comment: Вам нужно смотреть эти файлы, чтобы понять, как подключить библиотеку к своему проекту.

Comment: Ну я посмотрел, что именно я должен был понять? В Qt нужно подключать файлы через зависимости include, не знаю как организовать это здесь, потому что там много файлов и я не вижу вс дерево зависимостей внутри CLucene, если у вас уже есть готовое решение не можете скинуть его?

Comment: *"не знаю как организовать это здесь"* - ну так посмотрите, как файлы библиотеки подключаются в примере и делайте у себя по аналогии.